# Interrupted message is showing on browser screen and not able to see browser screen?

Tags: orientdb

I downloaded latest OrientDB version 2.2.17. I started server without any error on console and in log file but when I tried to open browser its showing interrupted on browser. I am not able to see the browser screen when I tried to connect using console its connected. How I fix it so I can see the browser also?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an Internet Explorer issue, try with Chrome or Firefox, they both works for me.

Hope it helps.

Regards,
Michela

Comment: If my answer is correct, please mark it as such. Thx